# Empty django models

Tags: python, django, models

Hi I'm getting tottaly empty Comments. And I don't really know why.

Here is my view file.

```
    from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
    from .forms import PostForm
    from django.views.generic import TemplateView
    from .forms import CommentForm
    from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
    from .models import Post

    class createPost(TemplateView):
        template_name = 'forum/createPost.html'

        def get(self, request):
            form = PostForm()
            return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

        def post(self, request):
            form = PostForm(request.POST)
            if(form.is_valid()):
                form.save()
                return redirect('/forum')

    def add_comment(request, pk):
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
        if(request.method == 'POST'):
            form = CommentForm(request.POST)
            if(form.is_valid()):
                comment = form.save(commit=False)
                comment.post = post
                comment.save()
                return redirect('/forum/')
        else:
            form = CommentForm()
        template = 'forum/addComment.html'
        context = {'form': form}
        return render(request, template, context)
```

And here is my models file

```
    from django.db import models

    class Post(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=140)
        body = models.CharField(max_length=500)
        date = models.DateTimeField()

        def __str__(self):
            return self.title

    class Comment(models.Model):
        post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='comments', null=True,         on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
        com_title = models.CharField(max_length=140)
        com_body = models.CharField(max_length=500)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.com_title
```

And lastly here is forms

```
   from django import forms
   from .models import Post, Comment

   class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
       title = forms.CharField(max_length=140)
       body = forms.CharField()
       date = forms.DateTimeField()

       class Meta:
           model = Post
           fields = ('title', 'body', 'date')

   class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
       title = forms.CharField(max_length=140)
       body = forms.CharField(max_length=500)

       class Meta:
           model = Comment
           fields = ('title', 'body')
```

I don't really know why I'm getting this error. I get a comment but It is totaly blank. Mabye It has something to do with the comment = form.save(commit=False), but i don't know.

I am really new to Django so please let me know if you know how to solve it. Also if there is somthing more I have to add to this question like urls and stuff please let me know.
Thanks ;)

Comment: What exactly happens? When are you getting empty posts? What have you tried so far (with the debugger or maybe putting print statements in the code)?

Comment: Don't you need to inherit `CreateView` instead of `TemplateView` inside `createPost` ?

Comment: Print out the attributes of you comment before you save it. If empty, print out the attributes of your form, and so on until you find where it goes wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your view to

```
class createPost(CreateView):
         template_name = 'forum/createPost.html'
         model=Post
         form_class=PostForm
         def form_valid(self, form):
             form.save()
             return http.HttpResponseRedirect('/forum')
```

and then form to

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

       class Meta:
           model = Post
           fields = ('title', 'body', 'date')
```

PS: If you don't want to make any changes to your form fields, then form_class is not required. You may provide the fields to the View itself.

Comment: I am very sorry I ment to say that my Comments were totaly empty. Im really sorry. But thanks anyway ;)